# Ignoring specific overloaded methods with Swig

Tags: swig

I'm making a wrapper of a C++ library so it can be used from Java, I'm doing this with Swig.

What I'm facing is that i have a Class `SomeClass`, which has some overloaded methods (`someMethod`). Of this overloaded methods some receive complex data that i don't want to export to the wrapper, and some simple ones which i do want then exported.

I'm trying to use the `%rename("$ignore")` directive but either i get all methods exported or none. I have another two types of Classes `SimpleData` and `ComplexData`, one of them in namespace `ns1` and the other in `ns2`, `SomeClass` is in namespace ''ns3`.

The class `SimpleData`:

```
#ifndef SIMPLEDATA_H_
#define SIMPLEDATA_H_

namespace ns1 {

class SimpleData {
public:
    SimpleData(){}
    virtual ~SimpleData(){}
};

} /* namespace ns1 */
#endif /* SIMPLEDATA_H_ */
```

The class ComplexData:

```
#ifndef COMPLEXDATA_H_
#define COMPLEXDATA_H_

namespace ns2 {

class ComplexData {
public:
    ComplexData(){}
    virtual ~ComplexData(){}
};

} /* namespace ns2 */
#endif /* COMPLEXDATA_H_ */
```

The class `SomeClass`:

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H_
#define SOMECLASS_H_

#include "SimpleData.h"
#include "ComplexData.h"

namespace ns3 {

class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass(){}
    bool someMethod(const ns1::SimpleData & data){return true;}
    bool someMethod(const ns2::ComplexData & data){return true;}
    bool someMethod(const int & data){return true;}
    bool anotherMethod();
    virtual ~SomeClass(){}
};

} /* namespace ns3 */
#endif /* SOMECLASS_H_ */
```

The i file snippet looks like this:

```
%rename ("$ignore", fullname=1) "ns3::SomeClass::someMethod(const ns2::ComplexData&)";
```

But that isn't working. Which one is the correct way of ignoring some specific overload of a method?

The full .i file:

```
%module libSomeClass

%{
    #include "../src/SomeClass.h"
%}

%pragma(java) jniclasscode=%{
  static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("SWIG_C++");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load. \n" + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
%}

// SimpleData
%include "../src/SimpleData.h"

//removes too much
//%rename ("$ignore", fullname=1) "ns3::SomeClass::someMethod";

//does not work
%rename ("$ignore", fullname=1) "ns3::SomeClass::someMethod(const ns2::ComplexData &)";

%rename ("renamedMethod", fullname=1) "ns3::SomeClass::anotherMethod";

%include "../src/SomeClass.h"
```

Note: I don't think it actually has nothing to do but just in case, those methods actually throw a exception.

Note2: I also don't think is relevant, but the target language is Java and the source language is C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to **not** use quotes with the method signature.

```
%rename ("$ignore", fullname=1) ns3::SomeClass::someMethod(const ns2::ComplexData &);
```

I did put quotes in the first place because I always have and always worked for me, for example:

```
%rename ("renamedMethod", fullname=1) "ns3::SomeClass::anotherMethod";
```

The full .i file for reference:

```
%module libSomeClass

%{
    #include "../src/SomeClass.h"
%}

%pragma(java) jniclasscode=%{
  static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("SWIG_C++");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load. \n" + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
%}

// SimpleData
%include "../src/SimpleData.h"

%rename ("$ignore", fullname=1) ns3::SomeClass::someMethod(const ns2::ComplexData &);

%ignore ns3::SomeClass::someMethod(const int &);

%rename ("renamedMethod", fullname=1) "ns3::SomeClass::anotherMethod";

%include "../src/SomeClass.h"
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using just the %ignore directive, http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_rename_ignore?  Check out http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#ambiguity_resolution_renaming to see how to best match the function you want to ignore.

Also note that "The placement of the %rename directive is arbitrary as long as it appears before the declarations to be renamed", is your %rename before the function?

(In your example you are missing the class name, I assume that is just a typo right?)

Comment: The documentation states that `%ignore` and `%rename("$ignore")` [are exactly the same](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_advanced_renaming) except that `%rename` is a little bit more flexible. Yes, my `%rename` is before the function declaration (more precisely before the `%include`). Yes, the lack of a class name is a typo. I've been able to find a solution, it appears to be an issue with using **quotes** in the method signature, odd. Anyway thanks for your answer, it makes me go through the docs again and thanks to that i realized the examples do not have quotes.