# SWIG - How to ignore C++ classes I don't need to expose (in Java)?

Tags: java, c++, swig

Consider a `SomeClass.h` with the following functions declared

```
void doSomethingSimple(double);
void dealWithComplexClasses(ComplexClass&);
```

I want to expose `doSomethingSimple(double)` in Java, but NOT `dealWithComplexClasses(ComplexClass&)`

I have tried various things such as:

```
%ignore SomeClass::dealWithComplexClasses(ComplexClass&);
%ignore SomeClass::dealWithComplexClasses;
```

I also found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17451877/990616) which is answered but did not help me (while the problem is similar so I must be missing something)
But in the end Swig always creates a proxy java class for ComplexClass and there is a `dealWithComplexClasses(SWIGTYPE_p_ComplexClass class)` in the `SomeClass.java`

How can I tell Swig to generate code only for what I want to expose in Java ? Or to ignore functions and classes I don't want to expose?

Comment: Note that if you're not attached to swig, Boost.Python does this kind of things very well.

Answer (score 11):

You are doing the right thing. The `%ignore SomeClass::dealWithComplexClasses` should have worked so I suspect you were trying other things at the same time and interpreted errors as indication that this hadn't worked.  Try:

```
%ignore ComplexClass; // will not wrap ComplexClass
%ignore SomeClass::dealWithComplexClasses; // do not wrap that method or any of its overloads
```

Another possibility but can't tell from your post, is that your class is in a namespace. In this case you need the namespace prepended.

If it still doesn't work, need more info, post a minimal .i and .h for this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use preprocessing tools directly in your C++ code :

```
void doSomethingSimple(double);
#ifndef SWIGJAVA
void dealWithComplexClasses(ComplexClass&);
#endif
```

See : http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Preprocessor.html#Preprocessor_condition_compilation